# Experienced sound volume issues with Tokbox/Vonage Video API on iPhone to iPhone calls?

Tags: ios, webrtc, tokbox, vonage

We've implemented Vonage's Video API in our application without any significant problems until we recently noticed a very low sound volume for one of the two participants on a video call when the participants are both using iPhones - both Chrome and Safari browsers. This was even when the phone volume setting was on full. Both phones are on the latest iPhone software 15.2.

Has anyone experienced a similar problem and found a solution?

Thanks

Comment: Hi looking into this for you, are you able to test on a previous iOS version?

Comment: I believe this is related to an iOS issue. See https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=230902
When you allow permissions to the mic, the volume goes down.

Comment: Sorry - further testing seems to show that upgrading to 15.2 did actually fix the issue. Thanks Abdulajet and Germán Goldenstein for your comments. Appreciated.